# What do you do in order not to forget what you have learned some time ago?

Tags: education, advice, learning

I have been trying to find ways to retain the Math knowledge I have previously learned, for example, last Spring I took Linear Algebra and passed it with an A, but now I can't remember the simplest things about it even though it was only around 7 months ago. Similarly, I took discrete Mathematics, Single and Multi-variable calculus, and can barely remember anything from them as well so it feels like I know nothing at this point. Are there any tips to keep that knowledge in mind? I took Probability & Statistics this semester and I am trying to answer questions here as much as possible as this might help to keep things in mind.

Comment: what helped me is to make super condensed notes. The idea was to reduce the information to the smallest things I needed to be able to recreate the rest of the information. I still forgot things so I guess there's no replacement for practice

Comment: @Sergo If you went through the topic once and understood it enough to solve problems, a note of formulas and a few examples would help to recollect the same after sometime. Also try more new problems each time to use old knowledge.

Comment: You always must have motivation when learning a certain topic, see how theorems are connected to other theorems. If your studies are purely theoretical try to draw graphs, visualizations, geometrical figures.... Concerning probability and statistics I would recommend to categorize any examples/exercises/problems you encounter under which theorem, rule they lie into. You will see that so many examples are just different interpretations of the same problem that is applicable under a certain theorem.

Comment: thank you everyone!

Comment: You might be interested in "spaced repetition": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition